# django updating user profile using modelform

Tags: django, django-forms

## views.py

```
def profile(request,nav="profile",template="profile.html",context = {},extra_context = None):
    if request.POST:
        if 'profileFormSubmit' in request.POST:
            pform = UserProfileForm(request.POST,instance = request.user)
            if pform.is_valid():
                user = pform.save()

                return redirect(profile,nav="account")
            else:
                context['data'] ={'nav_menu': ['account','profile','reviews','favourites'],
                'cur_nav':nav}
                context['pform'] = pform
                context['rform'] = PartialSignupForm()
                context['lform'] = LoginForm()
                context['aform']  = AccountsForm()
                return render_to_response(template,context,context_instance = RequestContext(request))
        else:
            return redirect(profile,nav="profile")


    else:
        context['rform'] = PartialSignupForm()
        context['lform'] = LoginForm()
        context['aform']  = AccountsForm()

        context['pform'] = UserProfileForm(instance = request.user)
        context['data'] ={'nav_menu': ['account','profile','reviews','favourites'],
               'cur_nav':nav}
        context['reviews'] = request.user.review_set.all()
        if extra_context is not None:
            context.update(extra_context)
        return render_to_response(template,context,context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

## forms.py

```
class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    sex = forms.CharField(max_length = 20,label="I am :",widget=forms.Select(choices=SEX_CHOICES,attrs = {'class':''}),required = False)
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length = 50,widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Please enter your real name.','class':''}),required = False)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length = 50,widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Enter last name.','class':''}),required = False)
    location = forms.CharField(max_length = 50,widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Enter your current location','class':''}),required = False)
    def clean_first_name(self):
        first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        if first_name == '':
            raise forms.ValidationError("This field is required.")
        return first_name
    def clean_phone(self):
        phone = self.cleaned_data['phone']
        if phone == '':
            raise forms.ValidationError("This field is required.")
        return phone

    def clean_last_name(self):
        last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        if last_name == '':
            raise forms.ValidationError("This field is required.")
        return last_name

    def clean_profession(self):
        profession = self.cleaned_data['profession']
        if profession == "":
            raise forms.ValidationError("Select a valid option.")
        return profession

    def clean_sex(self):
        sex = self.cleaned_data['sex']
        if sex == "":
            raise forms.ValidationError("Select a valid option.")
        return sex
    def clean_location(self):
        location = self.cleaned_data['location']
        if location == "":
            raise forms.ValidationError("This field is required.")
        return location

    def __init__(self,*args,**kw):
        super(UserProfileForm,self).__init__(*args,**kw)
        self.phone = self.instance.get_profile().phone
        self.profession = self.instance.get_profile().profession
        self.sex = self.instance.get_profile().sex
        self.location = self.instance.get_profile().location        

    def save(self,*args,**kw):
        self.instance.first_name = self.cleaned_data.get("first_name")
        self.instance.last_name = self.cleaned_data.get("last_name")
        profile = self.instance.get_profile()
        profile.sex = self.cleaned_data.get("sex")
        profile.location = self.cleaned_data.get("location")
        profile.profession = self.cleaned_data.get("profession")
        profile.phone = self.cleaned_data.get("phone")
        profile.save()
        self.instance.save()
        return self.instance

    class Meta:
        model = User
        #fields = ('username','email','password','confirm_password','first_name','last_name','sex','phone','profession')
        fields = ('first_name','last_name','phone','sex','profession','location')
```

## models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length = 40,blank=False,default = "")
    location = models.CharField(max_length = 100,blank=False,default = "")
    sex = models.CharField(max_length =  10,blank = False,default = "")
    profession = models.CharField(max_length =  50,blank = False,default = "")
```

## doubt

i am not able to understand that when i am rendering the profile form to edit , only the first name and last name are there but when i fill the detail and submit the form its changes are made to the user profile  but on reload the profile form is not initiated with the values form userprofile , only first_name and last_name values are set , i understand that the form is a User model form , but still when i  am initiating it with the user profile values , y am i not getting the expected result , please help , thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

In `UserProfileForm`,

```
class Meta:
   model = User
```

needs to change to

```
class Meta:
   model = UserProfile
```

Comment: yea thats a solution for sure , but i want it for the model user only , thanks

Answer (score 1):

As Karthikr stated, your form is loading the values from the User model (first/last name) rather than the values from the User Profile. If you want the correct values to appear, you need to initiate the form based on the correct model (UserProfile in this case).